# JSON returning object Object not String

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4

The below code is returning [object Object] not a string.  How can I get it to return the correct string representation? I am using ASP.NET MVC4 C#.

```
public JsonResult Names(string name)
{
    var a = db.NamesToGet.Select(e => new 
    {
        name = e.Names                        
    });          
    return Json(a, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: return `a` as `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
var a = db.NamesToGet.Select(e=>e.Names);
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `try` without `catch`

Answer (score 1):

Access it with `data.name` or substitute `data` to your json variable name.

```
$.get("/Controller/GetName", function(data) {
   alert(data.name);
   //or alert(data[0].name);
});
```